# jquery.formatCurrency.js remove dollar symbol

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have been searching for info on this but can't find any.  I am pretty sure I have done this in the past but can't remember.  I want to be able to use this but not have the $ symbol in it.  Can someone list an example of how to use it and remove the $ out.

```
        $('.moneyField').blur(function()
            {
                $('.moneyField').formatCurrency();
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the 'symbol' as ' '. Which will remove the '$'.

```
$('.moneyField').formatCurrency({symbol: ''});
```

The default symbol is '$', but this option allows you to specify another symbol, or ' ', which will effectively remove the $.

Here are the [docs](https://code.google.com/archive/p/jquery-formatcurrency/wikis/Usage.wiki) for usage of the formatCurrency plugin.

Comment: thank you, I was missing the inside curly brackets when I did that earlier

Comment: Glad I could help. Please mark this as answer if you are satisfied :).